# SIP VOIP calling using Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sip, voip

I was trying to register to a SIP server using this code.. but when i try to run this code nothing will be shown.. I use android API to write down this code.. i just need to register my application to a SIP server.. if anyone knows let me know.. Thank You!

```
public SipManager mSipManager = null;
public SipProfile mSipProfile = null;
String username="100";
String domain="192.168.56.1";
String password="100";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    lbl= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);


    if(mSipManager == null) {
        mSipManager = SipManager.newInstance(this);
    }

    try {

        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username,domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);
        mSipProfile = builder.build();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        mSipManager.open(mSipProfile, pendingIntent, null);

        mSipManager.setRegistrationListener(mSipProfile.getUriString(), new SipRegistrationListener() {

            public void onRegistering(String localProfileUri) {
                lbl.setText("Registering with SIP Server...");
            }

            public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
                lbl.setText("Ready");
            }

            public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,
                                             String errorMessage) {
                lbl.setText("Registration failed.  Please check settings.");
            }
        });


       //throw new SipException();

    }catch (ParseException pe) {
        Log.i("STATE11","Connection Error.");
    }catch (SipException se ){
        Log.i("STATE11","Connection Error."+se);

    }
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: i want to register to a sip server using these information

Comment: same problem here, i've been searching for DAYS... android studio documentation is stupid and incomplete, did you find a solution

Comment: Sometimes the phone manufacturers block VoIP features, so always ensure you call this method, SIPManager.isVoipSupported() which returns a boolean, if it returns false, then it means your manufacturer has blocked VOIP